# Laravel authorization per user per organization

Tags: php, laravel, authorization

I have an unusual requirement for authorization. Our project has an app wide user table, but these users might belong to one or more "organizations", for each of which they might have a different set of permissions. I looked at existing packages for Laravel, and didn't find anything of sorts. Any clues?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is not that unusual. I think you are referring to 'multi-tenant' apps. There are some Laravel packages out there that can help you with this. Just search for them on [packagist](https://packagist.org/)